# Struts 2 Using Status Index

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure out how the status index works in Struts 2 (I'm using Struts 2.3.4).  I'm trying to iterate through items 5-9 in my **selectedValues** String List:

```
<s:iterator value="availableOptions" var="currentSelect" begin="5" end="9" status="status">
    <td><s:select list="currentSelect" name="selectedValues" value="selectedValues" cssClass="day-select" /></td>
</s:iterator>
```

But it is looking up the values like so: selectedValues[0], selectedValues[1], etc. rather than selectedValues[5], selectedValues[6]...

The only way I seem to be able to get it to work is by manually adding 5, which seems like a kludge:

```
<td><s:select list="currentSelect" name="selectedValues[5+#status.index]" value="selectedValues[5+#status.index]" cssClass="day-select" /></td>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just curious have you tried in this way `<s:iterator begin="5" end="9" step="1" var="val"><s:property value="%{#val}"/> </s:iterator>`. for more details look at this JIRA ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3314

Comment: Thanks, I realized that I should have formatted my name attribute that way: "selectedValues[%{#status.index}]".  Unfortunately I still can't get it to work correctly for the value attribute.  The begin and and end attributes count correctly (5-9) for my currentSelect list, but not for my selectedValues list.

Comment: So you're trying to get five select boxes, each submitting to the same action property, each showing the *n* th value of the `availableOptions` list?

Answer (score 1):

You  can try this  `availableOptions[%{#status.index}]selectedValues"`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in the following and see if it works:

```
<s:iterator value="availableOptions" var="currentSelect" begin="5" end="9" status="status" step="1">
        <td><s:select list="currentSelect" name="selectedValues" value="selectedValues[#status.index]" cssClass="day-select" /></td>
    </s:iterator>
```

Where `status.index` is the start end feature to use.
`Step` is to know how to start the count.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that unfortunately it still doesn't work.  It does appear to step correctly (by 1), I just can't get it to start at 5 using name="selectedValues[#status.index]"